# Data frame rows error when trying to build news.md in pkgdown site

Tags: r, pkgdown

I'm trying to build a `news.md` file for a `pkgdown` site, but when I run `pkgdown::build_site()` or `pkgdown::build_news()` I am getting the following error:

```
-- Building news ---------------------------------------------------------------
Error in data.frame(version = names(timeline), date = as.Date(unlist(timeline)),  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 7, 6
```

EDIT: From looking at the source code for `build_news()` it seems to be coming from a [section](https://github.com/r-lib/pkgdown/blob/main/R/build-news.R) (starting line 274) that checks CRAN for a package history (this package isn't on CRAN< but seems there is a very old one with the same name, which is possibly causing the issue). Is there a way to work around this, beyond changing the package name?

Thanks